# Symfony 6 - condition in route gets ignored on prod only

Tags: symfony, routes, controller

I set a condition in my route and it works on dev. When I switch to prod with `APP_ENV=prod` the condition is ignored and the route is always shown. I can't find the reason for this.

```
    #[Route('/myrequ', name: 'getMyrequ', methods: 'GET',
        condition: "'dev' === '%kernel.environment%'")]
    public function myRouteCustom(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, ResponseService $response): JsonResponse
    {
...
    }
```

I even tried with `condition: false` what also works on dev, but not on prod. The route is active always on prod.

Checking the documentation, searched code for dev or prod only features.

Comment: have you tried matches instead of ===

Comment: `condition: '%kernel.debug% === 1'` try this one

Comment: Both does not work. Like a said, even 'condition: false' does not work on prod.

Comment: methods: ['GET']  - weird side-effect?

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it makes no difference.

Comment: I found out the reason.  It was the cache.  I deleted the var folder and now it is working. omg